# Modeling Objective function using mixed integer programming formulation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, optimization, linear-programming, mathematical-modeling

I have the following objective function

```
max 2x1 -2f(x2), where
f(x2) = 3 if x2 = 0
and f(x2) = 2-5x2 if x2 > 0;
```

can anyone help me formulate it using binary variables?